# PDF Comparision Tool to test Bills

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I work for a Telecomusnications company as a Test Engineer. As part of my Job, I need to do a regression test to compare Bills each production drop. Could some one please suggest toos to compare PDF bills from Past release to cucrrent release? Tool should be able to compare Bill format, Line Spacing, Charges, Messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. I would suggest using something like PDFSharp to analyse your PDFs. The rest is largely an implementation exercise.

It will take a bit of code to get it working to a reasonable degree of accuracy.

You would pretty much need to code the thing from scratch. The good thing is that PDFSharp (or similar libraries) will take the pain out of analysing the PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem could be to transform your PDF into images and then automate some visual comparison on them. There are a couple of tools out there to do such tasks:

- [testAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2009/04/20/9557563.aspx)
- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)
- [PerceptualDiff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/)